# How to assign different webmethod in JSON Autocomplete textbox

Tags: jquery, json

I want to accomplish autocomplete textbox using jquery-jSON.I have two webmethods and depending upon the codition,need to change the webmethod which is call DB to fetch the record for autocomplete.Here is my code:

function VenderCode() {

```
var type = $("#ddl_Type option:selected").val();
var fuctionname = (type == "TO" ? "GetServiceCtr" : "GetVenderCode");
    $("#txt_us_vender_Code").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/po_multiline.aspx/' + fuctionname,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'keywords':" + JSON.stringify($("#txt_us_vender_Code").val()) + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {


                    response(data.d);
                    $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").remove();
                    $('.ui-widget-content').css('background-image', 'url("/resources/Image/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")');
                    $('.ui-widget-content').css('border', '1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/');
                },


                error: function (result) {

                    alert(result);

                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (e, ui) {
            $("#txt_us_vender_Code").val(ui.item.value);

        }

    });
```

}
  1st time i am calling this code inside the  ready() function,so its working fine.but when i change the condition and trying to call this code again ,its not working. also i change async: false.still its not working..Please suggest me how to do this..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you calling this code? Is this inside some function?

Comment: yes...1st time inside ready function,then inside a dropdownlist selected index change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be calling this code multiple times. The .autocomplete plugin should be wired only once, inside the document.ready. Then put the dynamic method retrieval inside your `source` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt_us_vender_Code").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var type = $("#ddl_Type option:selected").val();
            var fuctionname = (type == "TO" ? "GetServiceCtr" : "GetVenderCode");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/po_multiline.aspx/' + fuctionname,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON. stringify({ 
                    keywords: $("#txt_us_vender_Code").val() 
                }),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                    $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").remove();
                    $('.ui-widget-content').css('background-image', 'url("/resources/Image/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")');
                    $('.ui-widget-content').css('border', '1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (e, ui) {
            $("#txt_us_vender_Code").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

The source callback will be invoked any time autocompletion needs to be performed. It will dynamically retrieve the method name from the `#ddl_Type` dropdown and send an AJAX request to it. Also notice how I wrapped in a `JSON.stringify` the entire `data` parameter.

Comment: issue not solved.its not calling the "GetServiceCtr" webmethod.i m getting error message "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027servicectr\u0027.","StackTrace":".......

Comment: similar case 1st time working fine if i changed condition, its not calling that "GetServiceCtr" webmethod and directly comes to error part

Comment: What's the signature of your second method? What arguments does it expect? According to the error message you are getting there seem to be missing some parameter that this method expects.